# Win10 Powershell. Powershell scripts won't run since update to 7

Tags: windows-10, powershell, script

A previous question involved my using Winget to upgrade powershell from 5.1 to 7.x.  As I understand it, I now have them side by side. But I have a new issue.  I had been experimenting with scripts to identify and modify VLANs.  I could right click on the script, choose run powershell, and it would execute.  That is no longer true.  Nothing seems to happen.  I can copy the script into a powershell window and it will execute just fine, but right clicking the script opens the menu but 'Run with Powershell' does nothing.  On my laptop, which I did not upgrade, they still execute.

How to fix?

Comment: Side by side is by design. Yet when you did the install, depending on what you selected, you should have two options. "Run with PowerShell" and "Run with Powershel 7" Which are you selecting? PSCore is not 100% backward compact. So, your code needs to be modified to run in both. If that is what you are trying. Just create a simple 'Hello world" script and prove that out.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "copy the script"? Copying its contents? What happens if you manually invoke *the script* from a PowerShell terminal?

Comment: 1) I do not have an option 'Run with Powershell 7.

Comment: @postanote
1) I do not have an option 'Run with Powershell 7.
DanielB
2) Copy the text of the script from an editor and paste into Powershell window.
2a) What is a Powershell Terminal?  Is that different from the Powershell Window?  
2b) If I have a script D:\temp\vlanshow.ps1, what command would you suggest to invoke it?